# Double offset path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

The offset path tool is new for me, I just used it a couple times and it works really well for me. But since a day ago every time I use it, it creates 2 paths, or maybe 1 big path.

Let's say I'm trying to make an offset path, 1 inch bigger that the original. When I open up the Offset Path window, click on preview, then write 1 inch in the Offset cage,  it shows me two paths, as on the image below.

How do I change it to get just one path or vector?

[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to make heads or tails of this. What tool? What's not working? What happens when you try? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ok, Sorry for that, Im trying to make an offset path, let say 1 inch bigger that the original, when I open up the OFFSET PATH window, I click on preview, then I write 1 inch in the OFFSET cage, and it show me TWO paths (previus example) my question is: How do I change it to get just ONE path or vector??

Answer (score 3):

Your shape is an open path that's why it offset allover itself. try to close that path and it will solve the problem.

In the two examples below, the right star is an opened path from the top while the left star is a closed one.

[image]

Comment: THAT WAS IT! THANK YOU!! sorry I cant upvote you I singed up today :( (I will do as soon as I can)

Comment: never mind ... happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The Offset path command in the `Object Menu` **duplicates** the original path in a new location. This is how it works.

If you only want to *move* the original path, without duplicating it, choose `Effect > Path > Offset Path...`

[image]

Comment: I think he doesn't mean to hide the original path. because he said that he use it several time without problem and now he can't get the effect he use to be.

Comment: Who the hell downvotes Scott!

Comment: @hsawires possibly. I had some difficulty even understanding what the issue was.

Comment: oops ... :) maybe I did, forgive my sin  ;)

Comment: Im sorry if I couldnt explain myself good enough, the the problem was that it was a open path